# What exactly is the Avatar's ability to turn into another Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

During the course of Avatar: The Last Airbender Aang displays a different way to interact with his previous lives: by turning into them for a short while. He did this twice with Roku (once when confronting the Fire Sages, once when talking to Jeong Jeong) and once as Kyoshi (during the events of his trial in Chin Village). Not only that, but it also alters his Bending abilities. When Aang turned into Roku for the first time he managed to Firebend like a master, something that Aang had not even attempted at that point.

But what exactly is this ability? Is it some kind of Bending? Or is it something inherent to the powers of the Avatar, like being able to communicate with them? If I am not mistaken Korra never does this, instead communicating with her past lives a few times before the events of the end of Book 2.

Comment: I never saw it as a power or ability. Each of the previous Avatars exist within the current Avatar. I saw it as Aang allowing the previous consciousness to sort of take the driver seat for a few moments.

Comment: May also be a good fit for [Anime and Manga Beta](http://anime.stackexchange.com/). While the debate goes on about if this is "anime", they do have a tag for it.

Comment: @phantom42 But we have seen in all three times he did that he did take the shape of the Avatar in question and was recognized as such. So it's not just the consciousness taking the wheel, it's actual shapeshifting or some kind of Bneding taking place.

Comment: I don't know that his physical form actually changed, or if it was a visual thing for the viewer to show that it wasn't Aang necessarily directly taking those actions.

Comment: @phantom42 No, it was very much a physical transformation. The Fire Sages, Jeong Jeong and the people of Chin Village all managed to identify the people Aang transformed into.

Comment: If you say so. I don't recall that, but it's been a long time since I last watched the show.

Comment: @phantom42 Here's the relevant scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxHy_jXRJ5Y But it's important to notice he's not necessarily *physically* changing. The Roku form looks very much like a spirit projection.

Comment: Watching that video, I noticed that the Roku manifestation is quite similar in appearance to some of [Jinora's spirit projections](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/avatar/images/4/45/Jinora_explores_Lake_Laogai.png), which makes me think part of the reason Aang exhibited this ability and not Korra is that it's related to air benders' closer association with spirit powers.

Comment: @CreationEdge True, this Roku has a blueish tint to him. But the other time he appeared, and the appearance of Kyoshi did not have that color to them.

Comment: And some of the times Jinora spirit projected she also was not tinted. ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that while these shows are generally pretty straightforward, they do have [some notable examples](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_YbtB-SmLBo/T-0VU5-z-HI/AAAAAAAAAnw/vNrcqiO7ry8/s1600/korra-scream.jpg) of abstract illustration. It's possible that Aang might not have changed at all, but rather could have spoken with the authority and aura of the previous Avatar, which was recognizable in a more subtle/spiritual way to his audience. Obviously there's no way to confirm this, but it's possible, and it fits with other scenes (such as Aang speaking with multi-voice when sentencing Ozai).

Comment: @Nerrolken To be fair though, Korra's mastery of facebending is played for laughs and not as important to the plot as doing something to physically resemble a past Avatar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as an explanation on the matter, there is no official one, so it's unclear whether this is a spiritual projection or physical possession of the Avatar's body.

When [Aang turned into Kyoshi](https://youtu.be/j1vz8z1jk1w?t=3m43s) it was clear that Kyoshi had control, as she was recalling facts that were only known to her, not Aang. When [Aang turned into Roku](https://youtu.be/RxHy_jXRJ5Y) for the first time, he was also in the Avatar State, which makes the Avatar capable of power he doesn't know he's capable of too, not only the transformation to Roku.

*Some small Legend of Korra Book 2 spoilers coming up*

But there is one thing that might shed some light on the situation. Spirits have the power to physically possess humans, as shown in [The Beginnings, Part 1](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Beginnings,_Part_1). Combined with the fact that Raava uses this power to teach Wan and to aid him in battle (albeit in a less deadly way), ultimately bonding together and creating the first Avatar ([Beginnings, Part 2](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Beginnings,_Part_2)). Supporting the theory that the Avatar can use powers that only spirits are capable of.

I would speculate that *Raava used her powers to allow previous incarnations to temporarily possess the body of the Avatar*.

Making it a power exclusive to the Avatar.

**Credits to @CreationEdge for providing video material.**

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit: Another thing might have to do with the spiritual connection the current avatar has. As we know, Aang was an airbender who alone are very spiritual. He grew up with monks which instilled in him an importance on spirituality.
Korra wasn't the most spiritual person at the beginning as opposed to Aang who easily sought out the spirits. Great question! I hadn't really thought so much about that before.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a spiritual ability through Rava (the spirit of peace and light), because in *Avatar: Legend of Korra* we see Rava get destroyed, which makes Korra lose her connection with the past avatars.

Comment: What does this have to do with avatars turning into other avatars? Sorry I don't quite understand. Could you [edit] your answer to be clearer?